The Roman army has 2018 units guarding their provinces. Prove that after 64 days, there were no more provinces with at least 64 units.
Problem: The Roman army has 2018 units guarding their provinces. The Emperor was worried that when there are at least 64 units in a province, they might get together and overthrow the Emperor. So on each day, he visited one such potentially troublesome province and sent all its units to other provinces, no two going to the same province. Prove that after 64 days, there were no more provinces with at least 64 units.

I don't really understand this problem. If on the first day, there are 2018 units in province 1, the Emperor must send them to 2018 provinces. So the number of provinces must be more than 2018.

I would appreciate any help, hint, approach or solution
The problem comes from IIMC 2018 Keystage 3 (EMIC), according to https://chiuchang.org/imc/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/07/BIMC-2018_Keystage-3_Team.x17381.pdf, problem 6 from the Team category

Isn't 2018 the total number of units? How can a single province have all of them. Is that allowed?

We don't know that there are 2018 units in a single province. We only know that either all provinces have at most 63 units at the start, making the number of provinces at least 33, or at least one province has at least 64 units that are then dispersed to different provinces, making the number of provinces at least 65.

If a province has been visited by the emperor once, it can never build up enough units afterwards to warrant a second visit.

@Lieven Great idea

The total number of dispersed units is at least $64^2=4096,$ far more than the $2018$ actually available units. This can only be achieved if at least some of the units get dispersed multiple times. But for a province to be visited on day $n,$ it must have at least $64$ units at the start of day $n$ and therefore at least $65-n$ units at the start of day $1.$ All of these $64$ provinces are different (after one visit, the province can no longer accumulate $64$ new units in the remaining days). The total number of units in these $64$ provinces at the start of day $1$ is at least $\sum_{n=1}^{64}(65-n)=65.64/2=2080,$ again more than the total number of units available. This proves that even at the start of day $64,$ there are no troublesome provinces left.

Awesome. I love the idea of 65-n
